# Java Reports Tooling

Tags: java, report

My team looking of java reports engine. We are looking solutions as cheap as possible. What can you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete [gizmo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9396/gizmo)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216490/java-reports-tooling/1216503#1216503), you also have a comprehensive list of [free charting and reporting tools](http://java-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting) (including [Eclipse BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/), but also valid alternatives like [OpenReports in its free version](http://oreports.com/))

Answer (score 2):

JasperReports - free, OSS

Answer (score 1):

JasperReports indeed. It have a wysiwyg editor what works just fine [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?projectname=ireport)

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/) is quite powerfull. At least if I undertand well your question.